# i have stored the streaming twitter data in an o1.json file but i am unable to read all tweets

Tags: python, json, string

```
import json

with open('o1.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=(json.loads(line))
print data["text"]
```

o1.json contains the streaming twitter data, when i read this data in a python object, the data type of data object is dict, now i am interested in finding the value of text key, but this code only give me one tweet where as i am interested in printing all the tweets may i know how can i get all the tweets, i am working on a data science assignment of coursea.org

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `data` on every iteration of your loop, then print its text after the loop finishes - so of course you're only printing one value (the last one). Simply put the print statement inside of the loop:

```
import json

with open('o1.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=(json.loads(line))
        print data["text"]
```

Comment: after doing this its giving me all the tweets but in the end its throwing an error of Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script.py", line 16, in <module>
    print data["text"]
KeyError: 'text'

Comment: This means the json object doesn't have a variable called 'text' - which could indicate an error in your data file. Just replace the line with `print data` to see what it contains.